# Import of module 'requests' doesn't work even after successfully installing them

Tags: python, web-crawler

Even after installing the `requests` module for Python 3.7, I still can't run my code to get data from a website.

Error Code is as follows:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "D:/Crawler/venv/WebCrawler.py", line 1, in 
>       import requests
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'

Comment: How did you install `requests` via pip? If so can you run `pip freeze` and check if you can see `requests` in the list.

Comment: what's the output of `python --version`?

Comment: requests is shown to me as 2.23.0, but i did the pip3 installation. So i don't know what might have caused the problem.

Comment: requests is shown to me as 2.23.0, but i did the pip3 installation. So i don't know what might have caused the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A possible problem might be that you installed 'requests' for another python environment or python version itself.

Run `pip freeze` and check if `requests` is available in the command result.

If not you probably installed using pip, it would by default install for python 2.7, to install for python 3.7 use

`pip3 install requests`

If that doesn't work, check the installation path of your module and python path you are using with your python script/ ide.